# How to attach flysky receiver to racerstar all in one esc and flight controller?

Tags: quadcopter, esc, multi-rotor, flight-controller

I am building an fpv racing quad I encountered the following problem:

I have a Racerstar StarF4s 30A esc and flight controller combo and a Flysky 2.4ghz iA6B receiver how and where do I connect these together?

Comment: what does the user manual say?

Comment: It doesn’t say anything. That’s why I’m asking.

Comment: i think that you need to request proper documentation from the manufacturer

Comment: Ok I will try, thanks

Comment: Couldn’t find a manual online. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assist you and point you in the correct directions:

the manual for your Racestar FC and ESC is here (it is in picture form):
https://www.racerstar.com/racerstar-starf4s-30a-blheli_s-dshot-4-in-1-esc-aio-f4-osd-flight-controller-w-or-bec-current-sensor-p-195.html

What you want to do is use the PPM out from the Flysky iA6B, connect it to the PPM in of the Racestar FC shown on the connection page. There might be other options but this will be the easiest one i personally think.

for cheapish components like these there is usualy no manual and when they are not sold anymore you are buggered (if you did not safe the description images which showed how to use them). I can suggest you to save those instructions somewhere for your own good.

As many who are in the RC hobby may know, maybe this site is not the best for getting help with this type of problem (grown up robotics people tend to have opinions on petty RC-hobbyists) youtube (RCModelrewiews, Joshua Bardwell, ...) and Oscar Liang  or sites may be more informative.